# What is the Venkateswara Suprabhatam?

Tags: vishnu, mantras, temple, venkateshwara, source

M S Subbalakshmi's rendering of the Venkateswara Suprabharam (*"Kausalya supraja rama ..."*) is very famous.

But who composed it?

Is it recited at Tirupati Venkateswara temple every morning to wake up the deity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numerous sources explain that the Venkateswara Suprabhatam is the work of [Prativadi Bhayankaran Anna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prathivadhi_Bhayankaram_Annangaracharya). It obviously can't be traced back to scripture, so here, as a source, is a transcription of a scholarly conference.

According to the [Indian Art History Congress](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Proceedings_of_the_Session_of_Indian_Art/Hh5NAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=venkateswara%20Suprabhatam%20Prativadi%20Bhayankaram%20Annan&dq=venkateswara%20Suprabhatam%20Prativadi%20Bhayankaram%20Annan&printsec=frontcover):

> Sri Venkateswara suprabhatam is considered as the foremost of such suprabhatamas and praised for its devotional content and poetic beauty. It was composed by Prativadi Bhayankaram Annan Swamy, a great scholar and one of the eight disciples of Manavala Mamuni called as Astadiggajas.

As for whether it's recited at temples: according to [this book](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Sri_Venkateswara_the_Lord_of_the_Seven_H/10QgAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0&bsq=%22his%20ceremony%20is%20performed%22) (page 108), it is.

> SRI VENKATESWARA SUPRABHATAM 'Suprabhatam' is the *Melukolupu* or the waking up ceremony of the Lord of Tirumalai every morning. This ceremony is performed every day in the Tirumalai temple before dawn at about 4 A.M.

Comment: prativadi bhayankaran is scripture @cdr